# Javascript causing issues with responsive css

Tags: javascript, css, image, resize

I've been working on a site for a while now and I have a page that for the most part is entirely responsive using css grid, I do however have an issue with a set of images that I applied javascript to which cycles through the images on a time.  Only when the site is in it's smallest 1 column range and the javascript is being applied the grid areas bleed outside the viewport whilst the resize is applied to everything else correctly.  Has anyone else had this issue or something similar?

https://jsfiddle.net/2svyua4q/

```
<title>Katie's House - West Hull Based Childminder</title>
<link rel="ICON" href="images/KH_logo.ico" type="image/ico" />
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Brian Johnson">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="KHjscript.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style-grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="kHstyle.css">
```

Skip to content</a>-->

```
<header class="masthead">
  <ul class="contact">
    <li class="nav">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/KatieSummersChildminder/" target="_blank">
        <img border="0" alt="Contact us on Facebook" src="images/fBook_Icon_Black.gif" width="30" height="30"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav">
      <a href="mailto:katiesummers789@gmail.com">
        <img border="0" alt="Contact via Email" src="images/email_Icon_Black.gif" width="30" height="30"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="field">
      <input type="text" title="Search" text="Search" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="titlegrp">
    <img src="images/KH_logo.jpg" alt="Katies House Logo">
    <img class="title iresize" src="images/kH_title.png" alt="Katies House Title">
  </div>
</header>
<!-- .masthead -->

<main id="content" class="main-area">
  <section class="">
    <div class="subtitle"><u>Example of a day at Katie's house.</u></div>
    <div id="myGallery">
      <img border="1" src="images/Activity_1.gif" class="active iresize" />
      <img border="1" src="images/Activity_2.gif" class="iresize" />
      <img border="1" src="images/Activity_3.gif" class="iresize" />
    </div>
    <p>Our days may change if we have something different planned but a typical day during term time would look something like this.</p>
    <br>

    <table class="iresize">
      <tr>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Activity</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8:15 - 9:00</td>
        <td>
          <div class="tablecont">Children arrive.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9:00-11:30</td>
        <td>
          <div class="tablecont">Morning outing to playgroup/ park/ rhyme time/ soft play/ children's centre. Morning snack 10 am.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:00-1:00</td>
        <td>
          <div class="tablecont">Lunch time (usually a hot cooked meal)</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12:30-2:45</td>
        <td>
          <div class="tablecont">Child led play and some planned activities, naps for younger children, stories, rhymes etc... Children can choose from a range of indoor and outroor activities and resources.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2:45-3:15</td>
        <td>
          <div class="tablecont">Small after school snack at 3:30.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3:15-5:00</td>
        <td>
          <div class="tablecont">Afternoon tea (usually a lighter meal) at 4:30pm, child led play e.g. toys/craft/garden.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5:00-6:00</td>
        <td>
          <div class="tablecont">Quiet play/reading, tidy up time and parents picking up.</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
    <br>
  </section>

</main>

<aside class="sidebar">
  <div class="subtitle">
    <p><u>Site Navigation</u></p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidelinks">
    <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
    <br>
    <a href="About.html">About</a>
    <br>
    <a href="Sample_Day.html">Sample Day</a>
    <br>
    <a href="Gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    <br>
    <a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</a>
    <br>
    <a href="Enquiries.html">Enquiries</a>
    <br>
  </div>
</aside>
<!-- .sidebar -->

<footer class="footer-content">
  <p>Brian Johnson
    <br>&copy; Copyright 2016. All Rights Reserved</p>
</footer>
```

```
function swapImages() {
  var $current = $('#myGallery img:visible');
  var $next = $current.next();
  if($next.length === 0) {
    $next = $('#myGallery img:first');
  }
  $current.fadeOut('slow', 'linear');
  $next.fadeIn('slow', 'linear');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Run our swapImages() function every 7 secs
  setInterval(swapImages, 10000);
});

@media screen
  and (min-width: 320px)
  and (max-width: 479px) {
    .site {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
      grid-template-areas:
            "masthead"
            "sidebar"
            "main"
            "footer";
        grid-gap: 0.5em;
    }
.iresize {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

#myGallery {
position: relative;
width: 90%;
height: auto;
}

#myGallery img {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    }

#myGallery img.active {
  display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
}

.iresize80 {
max-width: 80%;
height: auto;
}

.site {
    max-width: 50em;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I didn't do so in the first place, not to be awkward but purely to gauge if this is a common issue that I'd not yet looked into enough. If that makes sense?

I'm happy to do so but felt if people could perhaps suggest a few possiblities I could go away and look further into them.

Comment: That's not how this works.  You post the code you've tried and folks will help you look for where your error is.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Whilst i appreciate that you clearly have greater knowledge in this area than I I'm not entirely sure i needed telling how to insert code the ctrl + k function was not working 1st time round for some reason so I refreshed and was going to redo in the morning.

Similarly i few times on here I have been pointed in the right direction without code when asking a well structured question and have seen others offered the same courtesy. I am not someone that likes to come begging for answers.

Comment: Just trying to help you get a code-based response.  Looks like you got some a nice, specific answer. :)

Comment: I understand, sometimes the tone of comments is lost on forums/text etc. I do still appreciate your help and advice :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the fixed width and height on the "myGallery" class.

```
#myGallery {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  /* Set your image width */
  height: 267px;
  /* Set your image height */
}
```

If we set these to max-height and max-width, like so:

```
#myGallery {
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    height: auto;
    width:auto;
}
```

it should adjust to mobile desktop and mobile

Comment: @Acadiandreamer no problem! If there's anything else let us know! - If it worked don't forget to mark it as the best answer or up vote it.